# Confusion with caching with memcached and django

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am caching a bunch of queries for some models in my django project. It appears that the caching itself is working, but when I wanted to do a test by adding a new model object, I noticed that right after the model was created, the query listing was updated to include the new model, which should be incorrect because the cache timeout was set to 1 unix hour.

Shoulden't we have to wait 1 hour before seeing the new model? Here is the code:

```
def home(request, filterBy = 'all', sortBy = 'popularity'):
    if not cache.get('home' + filterBy + sortBy):
        models = Model.objects.with_rankings(filterBy, sortBy, request)
        cache.set('home' + filterBy + sortBy, models, 3600) # 1 hour
    else:
        models = cache.get('home' + filterBy + sortBy)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Caching is generally turned off during testing / development.  Are you running the memcached daemon? what does the caching settings in your settings.py look like?

Comment: debug is true, the cache is daemonized and on though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `cache.get(key)` returns None not False or anything else if there is no value in cache. And you are not checking for it, you are just checking if returned value is true or is it not. Empty QuerySet is also false and probably it is your case.

It should be (also it is one cache get less):

```
def home(request, filterBy = 'all', sortBy = 'popularity'):
    models = cache.get('home' + filterBy + sortBy)
    if models is None:
        models = Model.objects.with_rankings(filterBy, sortBy, request)
        cache.set('home' + filterBy + sortBy, models, 3600) # 1 hour
```

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, nearly *every* caching library will return None , not False, when there is no value in the cache.  You should always read the docs for the library, but that's the accepted and expected practice.

Comment: but same as `not []` or `not 0`